# In iex, why `config_env()` can't be called?

Tags: elixir

My code is as follows, I just want to know current's env is test or dev. What's the problem here?

```
iex(8)> import Config
Config
iex(9)> config_env() 
** (RuntimeError) could not set configuration via Config. This usually means you are trying to execute a configuration file directly, instead of reading it with Config.Reader
    (elixir 1.14.1) lib/config.ex:111: Config.raise_improper_use!/0
    (elixir 1.14.1) lib/config.ex:218: Config.__env__!/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config is usually compile-time or application start-time, there is no "current env" once you are running in iex after your application has started.

From the docs for [`config_env/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#config_env/0) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the environment **this configuration file** is executed on.

This function expects to be called from within a configuration file.  Normally you would use `Config` to create application environment variables, then use [`Application.get_env/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3) to fetch those variables at runtime. It's an anti-pattern to write runtime logic that relies on knowing what the configuration environment was - instead you should get the specific data you need from application environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your remind.  'It's an anti-pattern to write runtime logic that relies on knowing what the configuration environment was - instead you should get the specific data you need from application environment.'